# using MARS regression on data with outliers - R

Tags: r, regression, outliers, mars

In some previous asked questions, I was told to not delete the outliers, because they contain valuable information.

After testing different regression, I came to the conclusion that until now, the `MARS` regression delivers the "best responses".

I know that `MARS` is very *robust* and there is no *a priori* knowledge about the data distribution needed.

But there are some question which I have about the parameters.

I'm using the `earth` function implemented in `R`

**data set:**
   [file](http://www.filedropper.com/data_8)

So I've got 5 variables, *price, livingArea, area, discrete, dummy* and I'm trying to explain `price` using the other ones.

[image]

as you can see, there are some outliers and a `log` doesn't really solve the problem.
Due to the fact that `area` can be `null`, a `log` won't be a good transformation idea.

**what I do:**

Because the answers from other questions suggested to use the raw data, 
I'm running now the regression through my data without doing any changes to it.

so my regression formula looks like this:

```
earth(price ~ ., data = data[,-1], weights = weights, penalty = -1)
```

I'm setting `penalty = -1` because I saw that doing this, the method defines more knots and also the results look better.

Also I tried to define the variables `discrete` and `dummy` as `factors` and use them as follows in the regression:

1. independent
2. livingArea * discrete or livingArea : discrete and `dummy` as independent
3. the same as at `3.` but changing `discrete` with `dummy`
4. livingArea * discrete * dummy

I must say that I didn't expect, that a regression with this variables as factors, will return such "bad" results.

**what I want:**

I want to use the model in order to predict the value of new data.

```
    livingArea area discrete dummy
1         87    0        7    0.5
```

The prediction of this observation should be `~ 330000`, but with what I'm doing now, I ain't coming not even close to this value.

I think that, having more knots increases the precision of the result.

**questions:**

- I don't really understand the parameters
- I created my model with different values for the `pmethod`, but the result was always the same. what's the point in choosing a method when the result will be the same?
- how could I determine if I have to set/change the values of different parameters like `thresh`, `minspan`, `nk`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't what you ask for, but I think it's pertinent to analysing the data and it won't all fit easily into comments.

1. What does `area` mean if some values are 0? As a matter of interest I found that `area` and square root of `area` don't help much any way. That matches the evidence of the graphs in the question.
2. The variable `dummy` is not (0, 1), so I don't know how to think about it, but it doesn't help much either.

Following earlier suggestions I fitted a generalised linear model with log link. The choice of family seems fairly unimportant, but I haven't explored much. These results are from Stata. Two predictors seem strongly confirmed, but the overall fit is not strong.

```
. glm price log_livingarea discrete, link(log)

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -3093.2279  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -3078.9355  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -3077.8055  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -3077.8052  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -3077.8052  

Generalized linear models                         No. of obs      =        238
Optimization     : ML                             Residual df     =        235
                                                  Scale parameter =   1.01e+10
Deviance         =  2.38043e+12                   (1/df) Deviance =   1.01e+10
Pearson          =  2.38043e+12                   (1/df) Pearson  =   1.01e+10

Variance function: V(u) = 1                       [Gaussian]
Link function    : g(u) = ln(u)                   [Log]

                                                  AIC             =   25.88912
Log likelihood   = -3077.805214                   BIC             =   2.38e+12

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               |                 OIM
         price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
log_livingarea |   .6915059   .0888826     7.78   0.000     .5172992    .8657126
      discrete |   .1974758   .0247692     7.97   0.000      .148929    .2460226
         _cons |   7.811162   .4801921    16.27   0.000     6.870003    8.752321
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not surprised that the model is not a spectacularly good fit. There are many possible predictors of house prices that are not in your data.

Comment: 1. `area` is the `lot area`. a house will always have a `lot area (garden, yard, etc.)` but an apartment will not always have a `lot area`. Of course that I'm predicting apartments out of apartment data and house out of houses data. 2. yeah I know that `dummy` is between `(0,1)` but I just hadn't a better idea for naming it. The thing is that I had a lot of variables and after working with 12 predictors for ~7-8 months, I saw that combining this predictors and reducing the dimension of the data works fine. Maybe this is not a good statistical approach, but it works.

Comment: the variable `discrete` is build out of 2 discrete variables and the variable `dummy` is build out of 4 dummy variables. `sum(dummies)/4` and that's why it not `0 or 1`.

Comment: I must say that in 85% of the I have a nice data with a few outliers and a robust regression can handle it perfect, but in some cases (like this one) the data is terrible and also is the result.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. As a matter of strategy, I would disentangle the `discrete` and `dummy` variables all the way back to the originals. Fit with all predictors, then slim down the model. The problem for anyone else with what you have done is that they cannot interpret those variables, which are just arbitrary composites.

Comment: Messy data are just part of the job: you do the best you can and move on.

Comment: I also decided to let go variables like `roomCount`, `bathRoomCount`, etc because those are mostly user preferences and they make the model complex. For example if there is an apartment with `livingArea = 90m²`, some people will prefer it with one room (loft) and other with 2 rooms, other with 3 rooms.

Comment: Sure, but in many problems like this, good predictors are hard to find. I don't worry about the complexity of the models I try if I know that I can slim them down.

Comment: my idea behind modelling/transforming the data like this, was to make it in such a way that an increase in any of the predictors should generate an increase in the price.

Comment: what makes my work ever worse is the fact that everything must be automatic calculated and predicted. The program runs, and he receives the data and must return the prediction. So I don't really have the luxury to do it manually. I'm doing manually only those regression which are very bad, in order to discover the problem and try to eliminate it.